# Как заморозить Elements после клика?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Я хочу исследовать html на странице. Открываю DevTools, там я нахожу нужный мне html и могу его исследовать.

но на нужном мне сайте есть такой блок, html которого появляется только после клика по определенному блоку, и проблема в том, что где бы я не кликнул в DevTools (или в любом другом месте), сразу же пропадает этот элемент и нужно заново кликнуть блок чтобы его отобразить.

я в Elements вижу его html после того как открыл, я хочу развернуть html, кликаю, и на странице этот (dropdown вроде) прячется, как будто я кликнул в не его.

как исследовать подобные элементы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле все оказалось просто! Может кому-то понадобится:

1. В DevTools переходим на вкладку Sources
2. Ставим галочку на Mouse -> Click
3. Кликаем на странице на элемент после которого появляется нужный вам элемент.
4. Возвращаемся на вкладку Elements и исследуем его сколько захотим :)

Comment: Для тех, кто не совсем прошареный в Devtools (как и я, но помог опыт с GTM). С правой стороны Вкладки sources есть вертикальные вкладки. В вертикальных вкладках ищем Event listener breakpoints>Mouse>click

Comment: @Makar все верно :)